# How to make pointers to chars in the second array

Tags: c++, pointers, char, cin

I have an array of chars. `n` is array's length

```
    char tab[n];
    cin.get(tab, n);
    cout<<tab<<"\0"<<endl;
```

then I create second array

```
char* t = new char[n];
for(int i = 0; tab[i] != '\0'; i++){
    t[i] = tab[i];
```

}

I would like to have pointers to corresponding element. I mean `t[2]` contains addres of `tab[2]`. Then I would like to sort array `t` so `tab` stays as it was and only `t` shuffles but when I make change in the array `t` for example

t[2] = 'a';

I loose `t[3]t[4]....`

EDIT:

```
do{
    for(int i = 0; i < n -1; i++){
        if(t[i] > t[i+1]){
            char* x = &t[i];
            t[i] = t[i+1];
            t[i+1] = *x
        }
        n--;
    }
}while(n>1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to have pointers to corresponding element. I mean t[2](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) contains addres of tab[2](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).

So try this:

```
char** t = new (char*)[n];
for(int i = 0; tab[i] != '\0'; i++){
    t[i] = tab+i; // or `&(tab[i])`
```

To sort the `t` array based on `tab` values, use `*t[i]` to access character values stored in location `i` of the `t` array.

See [here](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~pdiloren/C++_Pointers/index.htm) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) for good tutorials about C pointers.

Comment: char** t looks like 2d array. What about  ` t[i] = *(tab + i*sizeof(char));`

Comment: @Robert You'll get the answer by reading the tutorials I've mentioned. With a single `*`, you are defining a simple pointer, which can point to a single element (Notice: arrays are like pointers internally). But you need an array of pointers. You can have it with a *pointer to pointer of char*. That's why you need `**`.